# RPM Repo: Clone just Source packages

Tags: yum, repository

As part of a project, I need to rebuild source RPMs from the really convenient [Remi Yum repo(Source RPMS)](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/SRPMS/).

The search for some way to efficiently get those packages was not a very successful venture(common keywords lead to very polluted results on `Google`). `reposync` can do this, but only as an add-on to cloning the RPM portion of the repo. What I need is something that does this just for the sources.

Any leads to doing this efficiently?

Note: Inefficient solution already applied:

```
extractXPathAttr.pl 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/SRPMS/'  '//tr/td[2]/a[1]' 'href'  |\
    grep src.rpm |\
    xargs -I{} wget 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/SRPMS/{}'
```

(`extractXPathAttr.pl` extracts the required attribute of the elements specified by the XPath from the given URL. I'll put it up on [github](http://github.com/samveen/) once it's cleaned up and documented.)

Comment: I suggest you email remi, because nobody is mirroring his srpms, and you can't rsync them from him.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm hoping for an answer to this class of problems, not just a specific solution to my problem (which I have solved, albeit inefficiently as compared to `reposync`)

Comment: The solution to the _class_ of problems is rsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reposync` can be used for just the sources.

It does not matter if the source repo is enabled under `/etc/yum.repos.d/` or not.  Just as long as there is a source repo under there it will reposync with it enabled or not.

Make sure that you specify the name of the source repository along with the `--source` option:

`reposync -n --source -r foobar-source`

Versions used in this answer:

`rpm -q yum-utils
yum-utils-1.1.31-42.el7.noarch
cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try mirroring the contents of the repository:

```
wget --mirror http://rpms.famillecollet.com/SRPMS/
```

The `mirror` option already uses timestamping, so it's useful for updates of the local mirror as well.

Then use `createrepo` locally.